# Extract HTML from HTTPResponse

Tags: android, http-post, httpresponse

I am having difficulty finding a solution to this problem, so I am hoping you can help me. I am logging into a website using HTTPost. I can successfully log in, but still there remains a problem. When logging in, it first takes me to a "Middle man page" that redirects me to the main home page which seems to be using `Window.onLoad` function to redirect me. When I get the HTML of the response, it is getting the HTML of the redirect page. The website uses a session to keep me logged in, not a cookie. I just need to get the HTML of the FINAL page I am redirected to. Here is my code. Thanks.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
            "https://secure.groupfusion.net/processlogin.php");
    String HTML = "";
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs
                .add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                        "referral_page",
                        "/modules/gradebook/ui/gradebook.phtml?type=student_view&amp;sessionid=16beb2d321c8c845b751022a196dbeb1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currDomain",
                "beardenhs.knoxschools.org"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username
                .getText().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password
                .getText().toString()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        String g = httppost.getURI().toString();

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HTML = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        sting.setText(HTML);
```